# error not able to give styles and others scripts in index.html

Tags: angular

Hi am creating a dashboard and i need to give some links in index.html like this
 i have given the file in assets and gave the path.And am getting an error like
GET http://localhost:46/src/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED.
The path to the file is proper everything is fine. Can anyone solve the error.

Comment: Did you use the angular-cli to create the project?

Comment: yes everything i have added just have problem only with these scripts in index

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install jquery bootstrap font-awesome --save` to install jquery, bootstrap and font-awesome.

Then in your .angular-cli.json file add the bootstrap css file and bootstrap js file in the corresponding key.

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
]

"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Comment: what you want? Just to install jquery in your project? or something else?

Comment: its like for style things , font we include  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> these the same way i have included these--<script src="../assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/material.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>and am getting error

Comment: are you using angular-cli ? then i can suggest you a more convenient way for including this

Answer (score 0):

To add styles or scripts to a project created with the cli you should do it in the `.angular-cli.json file`:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```